# How many types of Rasengan does Boruto have?

Tags: naruto

I know that Boruto has at least two Rasengan, but I don't know exactly how many he has.

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! I had extreme difficulty understanding what you had written, so if my edit doesn't quite match what you wanted to say, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

There are a total of 9 Rasengans, and all can only be attained by combining the power of the tailed beasts. As of right now, Boruto has 3 types that he can use with the help of his Karma (Which was made to Boruto by **Koji Kashin** a Jiraya clone), the three types are **Wind Style Rasengan**, **High Compression Rasengan** & **Vanishing Rasengan**.

- **Wind Style Rasengan** was taught to him through an explanation by Kakashi then the **Wind Style Rasengan** evolved into the **High Compression Rasengan** which Boruto can only use once in extreme cases.
- **Vanishing Rasengan** Was created by Boruto as a result of his chakra nature.